# Position image on Navigation bar IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a couple of issues with positioning an image in my navigation bar (Xcode 5.1.1 IOS7).

1) The image can't seem to be moved to the left edge of the screen. There's always a small amount of white space between it and the edge.

2) When I rotate the screen, the navigation bar is shorter then when the iPhone simulator is "vertical".

Here's me code for the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    /*
        Put image in nav bar
     */

    UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TheLogo45p.png"]];
    //[myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myImageView];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
}
```

I'd love to be able to position an image without code at all, but this appears to be impossible in the visual editor. What am I doing wrong in my code?

Edit:

New Code: the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AACLoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *btnLogin;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *customItem;

@end
```

New Code: The .m file

```
@synthesize customItem;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    /*
        Put image in nav bar
     */


    customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TheLogo45p.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backBtnAction)];

    customItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -10, 0, 0);// Change as you wish
    //[customItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:+3.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change by using Image Inset :

***Storyboard:***

[image]

***Coding:***

```
    UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backBtnAction)];

    item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, -10, 0, 0);// Change as you wish
    //[customItem setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:+3.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: item];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I tried your code I got an error message saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'custom item'.

In my view controller I've put in "@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *customItem;" though.

Comment: That's your , uibarbuttonitom name. . . Hide the default back button . . Create your own

Comment: Seems I was missing the synthesise at the top of the file. I've put it in but now I've got a new error: Undeclared selector "backBtnAction".

See my edited post above for the code I'm using.

Comment: I've removed the button from the nag bar and references to customItem. I've put your updated code in the view did load and there's an improvement - I now see an image there of the right size but it's a solid blue box, rather then my picture. I still get the warning that there's the undeclared selector backBtnAction. How do I declare the identifier?

Comment: Please refer basics **https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html**

Comment: Some ex : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721169/adding-a-uibarbuttonitem-programmatically-to-uinavigationbar**